# Execute SQL sent via ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to show my database every 3 seconds without refreshing the page.
I wrote this code but I could not send SQL to the controller.

Could anyone help me please?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  function get_fb(){
    var a='';
    $.ajax({
              url : "{{URL::action('DataController@post_appajax')}}",
              type : "POST",
              data : { a : a}
            })
            .done(function(json){
                console.log(json);
            });


    }
setInterval(function(){get_fb();}, 3000);
});
        </script>
```

```html
public function post_appajax()
{

    if(isset($_POST['a'])) {
        $data = DB::select('SELECT * FROM catetory');
        return View::make('data.index')
        ->with('data', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: For the love of god, _please_ don’t submit a **raw SQL statement** to be executed by a PHP script. You’re just asking for your website to be hacked.

Comment: Do not execute any SQL statements that are sent from the client. Anyone can edit the client and send a request saying `DROP TABLE category` and your site will delete it's own table. Instead, create something like an API. You simply send it parameters and it creates the statement server side using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Some search i wrote this code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( document ).ready(function() {

    function get_fb(){

    $.getJSON('{{URL::to("admin/categories/al")}}',function(data){
            var tb = $("#data")
            tb.html('');
              tb.append("<tr><td>Temperature</td><td>PH</td><td>CLOR</td><td>DATE</td></tr>")
            data.forEach(function(elm){
                tb.append("<tr><td>" + (elm["input1"])/10 + "'c</td><td>" + elm["input2"] + "</td><td>" + elm["input3"] + " ppm</td><td>" + elm["inputDate"] + "</td></tr>")
            })
            console.log(data)
        
        });
        

    }
setInterval(function(){get_fb();}, 1000);
});



</script>
```

```css
Route::get('admin/categories', 'DataController@getIndex');

Route::get('admin/categories/al','DataController@al');
```

```html
 public function getIndex() {
  $data = DB::select('SELECT * from data');
  return View::make('data.index')
   ->with('data', $data);
 }

 public function al() {
  $data = DB::select('SELECT * from data');
  return json_encode($data);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  function get_fb(){
    $.ajax({
              url : "{{URL::action('DataController@post_appajax')}}",
              type : "POST",
              data : {action: 'refresh'}
            })
            .done(function(json){
                console.log(json);
            });


    }
setInterval(function(){get_fb();}, 3000);
});
```

PHP

```
public function post_appajax()
{

    if(Input::get('action') == 'refresh') {
        return DB::table('category')->get();
    }

}
```